# Transaction management concept

Tags: java, transactions, jta

My question is How transactions work?

Suppose I am updating a record in a transaction and another transaction also going to update that record.

1) My transaction read the value of that record and trying to update it.
2) Mean while second record also read the same value as the first and going for updation.
3) Before 2nd transaction commit the value of that record it was already changed because of  first transaction committed.

So how the data could be consistence in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose I am updating a record in a transaction and another transaction also going to update that record.

Theorically each transaction should to execute in isolation (for achieving the I of [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) properties) but in practice this has not much sense. It's all about a performance issue. A high concurrency application's database will not execute properly in this way.

The idea is to achieve balancing between isolation and performance. When the isolation level is decreased (e.g. COMMITTED READ that generally is the default isolation level) some kind of problems can appear such the one described in your questions (it is called 'lost updates').

> So how the data could be consistence in this scenario?

There are several concurrency control mechanisms that help to solve the 'lost update problem', e.g. [optimistic locking and pesismitic locking](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/TransactionJTA_Overview-Pessimistic_and_optimistic_locking.html). Wich one is better depends on your application requeriments.